# Iterate through array in WordPress using shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am pretty new with WP, though I know how to write basic plugin functionality and create shortcodes. I want to have my plugin return an array (a list of the user's favorites), but have the HTML defined in the post, not in the shortcode implementation. So I want to do something along these lines:

```
[user_favorites_fetch]
<table>
   [foreach user_favorite]
     <tr>
       <td>[foreach_index]</td>
       <td><a href="[foreach_var user_favorite.url]">[foreach_var user_favorite.title]</a></td>
     <tr>
   [/foreach]
</table>
```

I know how to embed the HTML in the shortcode definition of `user_favorites_fetch`, but I'd rather have a MVC separation and keep the HTML in the post. I *think* I can implement the "foreach" functionality in my plugin as a specialized `[user_favorite_foreach]` shortcode, but I'd rather use a built-in "foreach" type function, if there is one. I've searched but have not found anything so far, but then perhaps I'm not using the right keywords.

Is there such a built-in "foreach" function?

Comment: You could just use JS + AJAX where you already have a native `for/foreach` implementation instead. Why overcomplicate things like this?

Comment: What, and have `user_favorites_fetch` return a JSON object? That's certainly a possibility. The problem is, I see that as being way more complicated, because the whole point of MVC is to separate your view (HTML) from your model/controller (PHP or JavaScript). If I did it in JS, they'd be tightly coupled... I don't want my designer mucking in my code. I could build up a whole Angular-like structure, but again that would be way more complicated than just having shortcode implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this question, I have learned a lot about shortcodes. There does not appear to be a built-in way to do this. What I ended up doing was indeed to write my own "wrapper" shortcode to iterate, like this:

```
<table>
   [favorites_foreach]
     <tr>
       <td>[favorites field=index]</td>
       <td>[favorites_link][favorites field=title][/favorites_link]</td>
     <tr>
   [/favorites_foreach]
</table>
```

Unfortunately, it turns out that it's difficult to put a shortcode in an HTML attribute and I didn't like the tradeoff involved, so instead of a shortcode returning the link, I have a shortcode that displays the link's `<a>`...`</a>` tags, including the href. The `favorites_foreach` and `favorites_link` shortcodes are "wrappers", where they need to run their own content through the built-in WP function `do_shortcode` to process the shortcodes in their content.

This was a nice, simple solution that maintains the MVC separation I wanted.